# Cant create connected containers or enhancers for griddle

Tags: redux, react-redux, griddle

I'm trying to create an Enhancer for griddle v1.6.0.

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props
>   of "Connect(Row)". Either wrap the root component in a , or
>   explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Row)".

Here is my Enhancer

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectors } from 'griddle-react';

const { rowDataSelector } = selectors;

export default connect((state, ownProps) => ({
  hello: 'world!',
  RDZ: rowDataSelector(state, ownProps)  
}));
```

I have a similar problem if I try to create my own Container

---

**EDIT**

It appears that the connect is actually connecting to my app's store (which I haven't added a provider for) instead of griddle's internal store.  I'm not sure how to access griddle's internal store in an enhancer, or container...  Maybe I am missing something here, should I be adding selectors instead?

Answer (score 0):

This a current limitation/bug with Griddle (I think). 
I worked around this by passing by data from the app redux to simple component, then that component hands the data to Griddle.

This is not ideal, but works for now. 
This discussion maybe of some help.
https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/issues/647